# Can we use https:// links inside the XML of an Excel file?

Tags: excel, xml, https

Can we use https:// links inside of Microsoft Excel XML files? Or do they need to remain as http:// links for compatibility reasons?

Simple example using '[Content_Types].xml' in an Excel XLSX file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Types xmlns="https://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"><Override PartName="/_rels/.rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/><Override PartName="/xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/><Override PartName="/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml"/><Override PartName="/xl/workbook.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml"/><Override PartName="/xl/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml"/><Override PartName="/docProps/app.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml"/><Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml"/>
```

Will Excel accept this file, or will it blow up?

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Excel in Microsoft Office LTSC Professional Plus 2021 as of today (2023-07-26), Excel refuses to load the XLSX that uses https:// in '[Content_Types].xml', saying "Excel cannot open the file FILENAME because the file format or file extension is not valid."

This was tested by unzipping an XLSX file, then manually changing '[Content_Types].xml' to use an https:// link and rezipping the XLSX. The original version of the XLSX and a rezipped version of the XLSX opened fine, while the modified version (using 1 https:// link) blows up with the above message.